# Laravel 5.x File upload not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have written code to upload an image. The code is always failing to upload a file. Please tell me what am i doing wrong here

My unit test is as follows

```
class FileTest extends TestCase {

 private $file;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->file = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile(
           'D:/work/gw.png',
            'gw.png',
            'image/png',
            filesize('D:/work/gw.png'),
            null,
            true // for $test
        );
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_uploads_a_valid_file()
    {

              $content = $this->post('users/login', ['password' => 'mypass',
                    'email' => 'james.bond@gmail.com'])->response->getContent();

        $data = json_decode($content);
        $token = $data->token;


        $this->call('POST', 'files/uploadcardimage', [], [], ['image' => $this->file],
            ['accept' => 'application/png' , 'HTTP_Authorization' => $token]);

        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }
}
```

Controller code

```
 public function uploadfile(Request $request){
      $file = $request->file('image');

      if( $file->isValid())
      {
          echo "Yes it is valid";

      }
      else
      {
           echo "not valid";
      }

       $dir = 'D:/storage/userfiles/78/';
      //Move Uploaded File
      $destinationPath = $dir;
      $file->move($destinationPath);
      return response()->json(['success' => '1']);
   }
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('files/uploadcardimage', ['middleware'=>'jwt.auth', 'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadfile'])->name('files.upload');
```

Stack Trace

```
[2017-01-16 15:28:15] testing.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException' with message 'The file "gw.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.' in C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\File\UploadedFile.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\app\Http\Controllers\FilesController.php(117): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile->move('D:/storage/user...')
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\FilesController->uploadfile(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('uploadfile', Array)
#4 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\FilesController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'uploadfile')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\FilesController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'uploadfile')
#11 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'uploadfile')
#12 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\app\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(18): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#44 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#57 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#62 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php(515): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\tests\FileTest.php(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->call('POST', 'files/uploadcar...', Array, Array, Array, Array)
#65 [internal function]: FileTest->it_uploads_a_valid_file()
#66 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php(909): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(FileTest), Array)
#67 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php(768): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#68 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestResult.php(612): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#69 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php(724): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(FileTest))
#70 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#71 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#72 C:\Users\John\Dropbox\hurry2.0\trunk\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(440): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#73 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#74 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#75 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#76 {main}  
[2017-01-16 15:28:15] testing.ERROR: #######Unknown error. This exception is not handled by the Handler. Attaching the message ########## 0=The file "gw.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error. ["#0 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\FilesController.php(117): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\UploadedFile->move('D:/storage/user...')\n#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\FilesController->uploadfile(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#2 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(80): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#3 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(146): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('uploadfile', Array)\n#4 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\FilesController), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), 'uploadfile')\n#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#6 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#8 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#9 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))\n#10 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\FilesController), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 'uploadfile')\n#11 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(174): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 'App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...', 'uploadfile')\n#12 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(140): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#13 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(724): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#15 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#16 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\JWTAuthenticate.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#17 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Middleware\\JWTAuthenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#18 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#20 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#21 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(18): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#22 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#23 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#25 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#26 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#27 [internal function]: Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#28 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#30 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#31 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#33 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#34 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#35 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#36 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#37 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#38 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#39 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#40 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#41 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#42 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#43 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#44 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#45 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#46 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#47 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#48 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(726): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))\n#49 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(699): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#50 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(675): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#51 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#53 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#54 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#55 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))\n#56 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#57 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#58 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#59 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#60 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#61 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))\n#62 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#63 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\Concerns\\MakesHttpRequests.php(515): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#64 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\tests\\FileTest.php(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\TestCase->call('POST', 'files/uploadcar...', Array, Array, Array, Array)\n#65 [internal function]: FileTest->it_uploads_a_valid_file()\n#66 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\Framework\\TestCase.php(909): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(FileTest), Array)\n#67 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\Framework\\TestCase.php(768): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()\n#68 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\Framework\\TestResult.php(612): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()\n#69 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\Framework\\TestCase.php(724): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(FileTest))\n#70 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\Framework\\TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))\n#71 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\Framework\\TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))\n#72 C:\\Users\\John\\Dropbox\\hurry2.0\\trunk\\vendor\\phpunit\\phpunit\\src\\TextUI\\TestRunner.php(440): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))\n#73 C:\\xampp\\php\\pear\\PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)\n#74 C:\\xampp\\php\\pear\\PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)\n#75 C:\\xampp\\php\\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()\n#76 {main}"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but try this `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`

```
/**
     * @param $file
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile|string
     */
    private function getFileInstance($file = null)
    {
        if (!empty($file)) {
            $path = base_path($file);
            $file = new UploadedFile($path, basename($path), mime_content_type($path), filesize($path), null, true);
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller code `$file->move($destinationPath);` to this:

```
$file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify both the upload path and the file name for saving the file.

```
$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
$fileName = uniqid().'.'.$ext; // renameing image
$file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName()); // uploading the file
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the file name in your controller try changing `$file->move($destinationPath);` to `$file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());`